# How to use environmental value inisde kubernetes yaml file

Tags: docker, kubernetes, yaml, google-kubernetes-engine, kubernetes-helm

I have one kubernetes deployment file for e.g:

I want that image_tag is passed at the command line when running the kubectl create -f deployment.yaml command. and suppose i did the export IMAGE_TAG=1.4.3 and want to use that ENV variable value is inserted at the position of image tag.

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  replicas: 1
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
     containers:
     - name: nginx
       image: nginx:{IMAGE_TAG}
    ports:
     - containerPort: 80
```

Comment: You should use the approaches listed in this bug https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/issues/52787

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do this:

```
sed -i "s/{IMAGE_TAG}/${IMAGE_TAG}/" deployment.yml
kubectl apply -f deployment.yml
```

as it is not supported by `kubectl`

Comment: that is a way I can do but is there any other by which I can achieve the same thing no by using the sed command

Comment: You can use `envsubst`

Answer (score 0):

most elegant way. you need to install envsubst binary

```
export key1=val1
export key2=val2
envsubst < deployment.yaml | kubectl apply -f -
```

Answer (score 0):

`Kubectl` doesn't support out of the box variables. Because it's tags based. For what you want to achieve you have different options. The most popular option is Helm, but,[Kustomize](https://github.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize), a new player is getting a lot of traction from the community. You can also use other tools like [Terraform](https://www.terraform.io/docs/providers/kubernetes/index.html) which I think a very decent option but unfortunately overlooked.